# where can I get JIRA API key

Tags: jira

Where do I get the API Key to create a Jira channel in Leverice? I can create the Jira channel within my workspace in Leverice (under the team channel). However, it asks for a Jira API key. What is it and where do I get this from?

Comment: This sounds like a question for Jira or Leverice support.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To obtain this token *you must have admin rights in Jira*.

1. Go to your Jira website
2. Click on your **Profile avatar** in the bottom left corner
3. Click on **Profile**
4. Click **Manage your account**
5. Select **Security**
6. Scroll down to **Create and manage API tokens** and click on it
7. Create a token, then copy and paste it back into the Leverice pop-up box.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply hit the below url to get API Token page

```
https://id.atlassian.com/manage/api-tokens
```

Answer (score 0):

For self-hosted instances [this answer](https://community.atlassian.com/t5/Jira-questions/API-Tokens-for-self-hosted-Jira/qaq-p/820644#M350896) from [Andy Heinzer](https://community.atlassian.com/t5/user/viewprofilepage/user-id/541137) on Atlassian forum may help:

> Jira Server does not provide those specific types of API tokens that
> can be used in basic auth, like Jira Cloud does.   If you want to
> create a token in Jira Server (self-hosted) for use in REST calls, you
> need to create an OAuth token, which has an expectation of creating an
> application link as described in [Jira Server Devleoper page on OAuth](https://developer.atlassian.com/server/jira/platform/oauth/).
>
> It is more setup and configuration for the use of a token in this
> case, but it a more secure method than basic auth is.
>
> If you don't need this level of security, then you could follow the
> Jira Server basic auth steps in
> https://developer.atlassian.com/server/jira/platform/basic-authentication/